# Wait till file is downloaded vb.net

Tags: vb.net, download, wait

I would like to know if there is a way i can make my application wait\ pause till a file is fuly downloaded.

the file is dowloaded ussing the folowing code...

```
'Downloads file from URL...
 Dim mywebclient As New System.Net.WebClient()
 mywebclient.DownloadFile(UPDATEURL & "/UPDATE.exe", "C:\mylocalfolder\UPDATE.exe")
```

Im ussing VB.net for those who would like to know...

Answer (score 1):

You could set the form's `Enabled` property to false when you start the download and use the [DownloadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx) event of the `WebClient` to set the Enabled property back to True. Not sure what else you might mean by wait/pause since that method is not asynchronous anyway.

```
'Downloads file from URL...
 Try
   Me.Enabled = False
   Dim mywebclient As New System.Net.WebClient()
   Addhandler mywebclient.DownloadFileComplete, AddressOf wc_downloadComplete
   mywebclient.DownloadFile(UPDATEURL & "/UPDATE.exe", "C:\mylocalfolder\UPDATE.exe")
 Catch
   'in case something fails
   Me.Enabled = True
 End Try


 Private Sub wc_downloadComplete(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    Me.Enabled = True
 End Sub
```